# Showing an AlertDialog once the activity has closed

Tags: java, android, callback, android-alertdialog, android-context

I am in the habit of passing `this` to any methods that take a Context. If I am inside an inner class, I pass `OuterClassName.this`. This may be bad practice, but I've never found a clear answer to what I should be doing.

I have an activity that loads some JSON data using Volley, and if there is an error the onError callback displays a Dialog (constructed with `OuterClassName.this` as the Context).

However, if the user has left that activity (pressed the back button) by the time an error occurs, the app crashes:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@422a88e8 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Of course, my activity *isn't* running. But I still want to display the Dialog. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By design, you should not to show any `Dialog` once your activity is finished. So, in your case, to stop popping the dialog window and avoiding `BadTokenException`, you may try something like this:

```
if(!YourActivity.this.isFinishing()){
   //show dialog on error
}
```

However, if you still insist on popping the dialog then what you may do is:

```
if(!YourActivity.this.isFinishing()){
   //show dialog on error
}
else{
   //launch a new activity which should take care of error msg dialog
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will use the first code snippet. My users wouldn't want to know an activity they aren't even viewing failed to load anyway, so it makes sense.

Comment: BTW It also works if I just write `if (! isFinishing)`, rather than `if (! OuterClassName.this.isFinishing())`

Answer (score 0):

1. Passing OuterClass.this is valid from inner class
2. When Activity is killed the view realted to the same wont be alive .

If you still wanna show some dialog after the crash end i would say create an activity as dialog and start that activity from application context . so even if you main activity is dead this activity will start after some background process .
You can use  `parent="android:Theme.Dialog"` as theme for creating activity as dialog